# Solr field with tens of thousands of values

Tags: solr, multivalue

I have a multivalued solr field, which is only used to filter the search results. This field contains a number of groups and if the user belongs to one of this groups then this document will be in his search resalt.

```
<field name="group" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="true" stored="false"/>
```

Since I have tens of thousands of groups, this causes performance problems.
Is there any better way to handle fields with this many values than `multivalued fields`?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to handle this is to transform the data into a single field with a custom character around each value, For Ex. if groups contain group1, group2, group3 as multivalued data, transform them to a single field containing single value of "||group1|| ||group2|| ||group3||" (double pipe being the custom character). Then you can use the same custom character around the group name during query time like for ex fq=group:"||group1||" to filter on group1. If you choose this approach, make sure to change the field type to the one that supports partial match and white space tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will increase performance. But I suggest try increasing

```
maxFieldLength (if you are using <solr4.x)
```

which is removed in Solr 4.0 if you are using Solr 4.X or newer,
try including filter for fieldType definition and increase maxTokenCount value. 
`<filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10000"/>`